# pushState: How to add the query string without redirect

Tags: javascript, html, url, pushstate, history.js

I studying the technique : History API pushState (HTML5)

I need the command for working the Url withput redirect because I have the server's CherryPy.

I cannot passing the data from Cherrypy (with Mako template to Javascript) but I want to change the url.

Old Url is

```
file:///media/DATA/prototypefin4/s.html
```

and automatically adding `foo=1&foo=2` (variable s) in the Url with History.pushState

```
file:///media/DATA/prototypefin4/s.html?=foo=1&foo=2
```

**But HOW?**

My COde:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example - History API pushState</title>
</head>
<script src="http://balupton.github.com/history.js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://balupton.github.com/history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>

<input id = 'button1' type = 'button' value = 'history.pushState' onclick="updateHistory()"/>

<script type = 'text/javascript'>

var count ="?foo=1&foo=2";

function updateHistory()
{

 History.pushState(count,null,file:///media/DATA/prototypefin4/s.html);

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it even possible? I can see some isssues with it.

Comment: I think that the possible error is on History.pushState(count,null,file:///media/DATA/prototypefin4/s.html);
Because there is a comment in a argoment
I working with my pc without the server.
What is the solution?

Comment: "I working with my pc without the server. What is the solution?" — Install [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is syntactically invalid. According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), the following parameters would be correct:

```
History.pushState(null, "", "file:///media/DATA/prototypefin4/s.html"+count);
```